# Deleting volumes when canceling a spot fleet request

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3

I am trying to write a `python` script that terminates a spot fleet.

The `boto3` API call `cancel_spot_fleet_requests()` conveniently provides `TerminateInstances` flag, that terminates all the instances.

Now I would also like to delete the spot volumes. I can do it in my script using `boto3`'s `delete_volume()`. The problem is that I must wait until the instances fully terminate, and it takes too much time.

Ideally I would like to mark the volume for deletion when the instance terminates, and have AWS do it in the background.

Is that possible? Is there an XY alternative? (my goal is to delete the volumes without having to wait long time in my script until the instances terminate).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution turned out to be extremely simple. Since I create the instances from a template, there is an option to do "Delete on Termination". I simply updated the template so the flag will be True.

[image]